# Visual Studio 2019 extension syntax highlighting and intellisense for Html in JavaScript string literal

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-extensions

Is there a Visual Studio 2019 extension that does syntax highlighting / intellisense to Html in JavaScript string literal?

This is for VSCode.  I would like something similar for VS2019. 
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bierner.lit-html

I can't find anything for recent for VS2019 and that is not for VSCode.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any one but what you can do is to type your code in a separate tab (with an HTML Extension) and transfer it to the string literal in your Javascript file